# SH Write a file with contents without any special chars

Tags: bash

So, I've got a challenge and it's as follows.

> You can access a normal shell(sh) on clean RHEL 6 installation. Write arbitrary content to `file.txt`, but without the following characters.

```
# & \ + - % @ = : ; , . ' " ^ ` ~ _ | ! / ? * $ # < > [ ] { } ( )
```

I can use like `touch file` or `rm file` but `touch file.txt` or `echo content > file.txt` is not allowed due to `.` and `>`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Use a text editor?

Comment: @forest, No `tty` or `pts`, so, not possible.

Comment: The file "file.txt" already exists and you just have to write to it? or you have to create it and write to it?

Comment: Can't you just use `tee` to both create and write to a new file without need for any special characters?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the non-alphanumeric keys, or can your commands not contain the characters? `tee` works fine for writing to a file if you can supply the input at the terminal yourself (some editors might work too, though you;ll have a hard time in `vi` without a `:` key), but you're going to have a hard time specifying the file name.

Comment: @CBHacking See OP's first comment.

Comment: Encode the shell script for writing to the file as hexadecimal and execute the result of decoding it, if you can find a way to do that?

Comment: @hft Create and write. Since `.` is limited `touch file.txt` can't work.

Comment: @Natanael Can you provide an example for that? Whether it works or not.

Comment: Something like eval or exec to parse decoded hexadecimal as script. Maybe you could even import special characters via getopts from the command line. Perhaps even use the read command to prompt the user to feed in a command and evaluate that as script!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple: check for python, perl or any interpreted language availability, then launch the interpreter and just code it !

Answer (score 1):

#### First having a look on permited chars:

```
00 E ''         10 E $'\020'    20 E \     46 - F     56 - V     6C - l      
01 E $'\001'    11 E $'\021'    30 - 0     47 - G     57 - W     6D - m      
02 E $'\002'    12 E $'\022'    31 - 1     48 - H     58 - X     6E - n      
03 E $'\003'    13 E $'\023'    32 - 2     49 - I     59 - Y     6F - o      
04 E $'\004'    14 E $'\024'    33 - 3     4A - J     5A - Z     70 - p      
05 E $'\005'    15 E $'\025'    34 - 4     4B - K     61 - a     71 - q      
06 E $'\006'    16 E $'\026'    35 - 5     4C - L     62 - b     72 - r      
07 E $'\a'      17 E $'\027'    36 - 6     4D - M     63 - c     73 - s      
08 E $'\b'      18 E $'\030'    37 - 7     4E - N     64 - d     74 - t      
09 E $'\t'      19 E $'\031'    38 - 8     4F - O     65 - e     75 - u      
0A E $'\n'      1A E $'\032'    39 - 9     50 - P     66 - f     76 - v      
0B E $'\v'      1B E $'\E'      41 - A     51 - Q     67 - g     77 - w      
0C E $'\f'      1C E $'\034'    42 - B     52 - R     68 - h     78 - x      
0D E $'\r'      1D E $'\035'    43 - C     53 - S     69 - i     79 - y      
0E E $'\016'    1E E $'\036'    44 - D     54 - T     6A - j     7A - z      
0F E $'\017'    1F E $'\037'    45 - E     55 - U     6B - k     7F E $'\177'
```

... Hmmm this is short!

#### Then

- So using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) variables are not possible, [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) do require a lot of signs, even [python](/questions/tagged/python), without `:` and `=`, we're short...
- using `tar` and `cpio` will require `-` on command line,
- using `uudecode` will require first data line to contain `-` and `.`
- same with `munpack` with a lot of `:` and some `="--"`,
- `dd`, `tee` and so on will require dot for extension....
  ( Maybe this: `tee file܂txt` (Note the dot `܂` is UTF-8 *`&#1794;`*, not a real dot `.`), then `Hello world` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, but no comment)
- If possible using an editor who will automatically add `.txt` extension

No.

From there You have to browse all your FS to find some alternative way or language, like [apl](/questions/tagged/apl), [brainfuck](/questions/tagged/brainfuck), [perligata](/questions/tagged/perligata)...

Comment: `xxd` accepts infile outfile (but needs `-r` as is). Maybe there's a similar tool that does the opposite.

Comment: `uudecode` will generate file, but first line must contain: `begin-base64 644 file.txt` so there is one `-` and always the `.` of extension.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a moot point if your challenge rules explicitly say you need a `.txt` in the file name but..

As this is a Linux distro I don't believe the extension should hold so much significance as the file will still be considered an ASCII text file provided that the first two bytes of the file do not combine to create a *shebang* or are other magic characters that would otherwise alter the interpretation of the file. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803434/do-file-extensions-have-any-purpose-for-the-operating-system) thread for further explanation.

You should be fine to use `tee` to create `file`, write all text to it without issue and then check that it is still a text file by running `file file`.

Comment: As I said, it needs to have an extension and write content. Not blank :(